# SphinxSearch Ranker=matchany on multiple fields

Tags: sphinx

Using Sphinx 2.1.4-id64-dev (rel21-r4324)

I want to search over multiple fields but do not want "duplicate words" to increase weight.

So, I am using ranker=matchany option.

this works as I want when duplicates are in a single field:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select id, val, val2, weight() FROM nptest WHERE match('@(val,val2) bar') OPTION ranker=matchany;
+------+---------+------+----------+
| id   | val     | val2 | weight() |
+------+---------+------+----------+
|    3 | bar     |      |        1 |
|    4 | bar bar |      |        1 |
+------+---------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

=> weights are equal, despite the duplicate word in doc 4.

But that do not work anymore when duplicates are over multiple fields:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select id, val, val2, weight() FROM nptest WHERE match('@(val,val2) foo') OPTION ranker=matchany;
+------+------+------+----------+
| id   | val  | val2 | weight() |
+------+------+------+----------+
|    2 | foo  | foo  |        2 |
|    1 | foo  |      |        1 |
+------+------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

weight of id-2 > weight of id-1

**Is there a way to apply a "matchany" ranking mode on multiple fields?**

Here is a sample sphinx.conf file :

```
source nptest
{
        type                    = mysql
        sql_host                = localhost
        sql_user                = myuser
        sql_pass                = mypass
        sql_db                  = test
        sql_port                = 3306

        sql_query               = \
                SELECT 1, 'foo' AS val, '' AS val2 \
                UNION \
                SELECT 2, 'foo', 'foo' \
                UNION \
                SELECT 3, 'bar', '' \
                UNION \
                SELECT 4, 'bar bar', ''

        sql_field_string = val
        sql_field_string = val2
}

index nptest
{
        type                    = plain
        source                  = nptest
        path                    = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/nptest
        morphology              = none
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to Sphinx 2.2.1-id64-beta (r4330) I was able to use [top()](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#factor-aggr-functions) aggregate function in a "custom expression ranker" like this :

```
MySQL [(none)]> SELECT id, val, val2, weight() FROM nptest WHERE match('@(val,val2) foo') OPTION ranker=expr('top((word_count+(lcs-1)*max_lcs)*user_weight)'), field_weights=(val=3,val2=4);
+------+-------------+------+----------+
| id   | val         | val2 | weight() |
+------+-------------+------+----------+
|    2 | foo         | foo  |        4 |
|    1 | foo         |      |        3 |
|    5 | bar bar foo | bar  |        3 |
+------+-------------+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That way, multiple occurrences accross multiple fields do not increase global weight and if fields have different weights, top weighted field is taken.

Many Thanks to [barryhunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65548/barryhunter) for his great help!

Answer (score 2):

You need the expression ranker
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting

can start with the default expression for the matchany and tweak it.

Using `doc_word_count` instead of `sum(word_count)` should be useful.

Comment: Yes Thank you, I think that's what I'm looking for. Just need to deal with user_weight now... I think I should take the top user_weight that matches but do not know how to for the moment...

Comment: Are you sure user_weight is what you think it is? Its the weight for the current field as set by the `field_weights` in the OPTIONS on the current query.

Comment: Yes I understand user_weight. But if the fields (val, val2) have different weights, I still want to increase weight of rows matching the "most weighted field" over others (I hope to be understandable :). For example if val weight=3 and val2 weight=4, doc id-2 (in my example) should have a weight of "4" vs doc id-1 a weight of "3".

Comment: Sounds like you want to use top(...) rather than sum(...) in the expression.

Comment: mmh yes, top() sounds great but it doesn't work like this: SELECT * FROM nptest WHERE match('@(val,val2) foo') OPTION ranker=expr('top((word_count+(lcs-1)*max_lcs)*user_weight)'), field_weights=(val=3,val2=4);
ERROR 1064 (42000): index nptest: Sphinx expr: syntax error, unexpected TOK_IDENT near 'top((word_count+(lcs-1)*max_lcs)*user_weight)'

Comment: yuor sphinx version is probably too old, ie old enough taht it was before top() introduced

Comment: Ok it seems like I should use v2.2.x instead of my actual 2.1.3 (I downgraded from 2.1.4 since my first post). Well, I'll try to upgrade soon and test. Thanks again Barry!